# go to URL using applescript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript

I am attempting to take have applescript open google and perform a search based on an array that I have set up.  This code works fine in safari but when I change the variable and application to chrome it isn't working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function run(input, parameters) {
    
    var chrome = Application("Google Chrome");
    chrome.includeStandardAdditions = true;
    
    var jsScript ="";
        jsScript += "window.location = ('https://www.google.com/search?q=" 
            + input[0] + "%2B" + input[2] + "+" + input[5] + "+" + input[6] + "&source=hp&ei=IBIkY5urBvjf0PEP1pSdwAY&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYyQgMDKSCknnouetXoh_tXAnLF5fZrJK&ved=0ahUKEwibu8ms0pj6AhX4LzQIHVZKB2gQ4dUDCAw&uact=5&oq=" 
                    + input[0] + "%2B" + input[2] + "+" + input[5] + "+" + input[6] + "&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAE6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQsQMQ1AI6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOggILhCABBCxAzoICC4QsQMQgwE6BQguEIAEOgUIABCABDoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQrwE6BAgAEB46BggAEB4QCjoHCAAQHhDJAzoICAAQHhAWEAo6BggAEB4QFjoFCAAQhgM6BwghEKABEApQAFi9QmCcSWgAcAB4AIABiQKIAYkfkgEGMC4xNC42mAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz');";
        
    chrome.doJavaScript(jsScript, { in:chrome.windows[0].currentTab});
    
    return input;
}
```

Comment: The command to run a JavaScript in Chrome is not the same as Safari - see the application’s scripting dictionary for terms and syntax.

Comment: Why use AppleScript at all? Automator and Shortcuts already provide actions for opening a URL in the user’s default web browser. That avoids the problem with different apps having different dictionaries entirely.